# Reduce size of image after Scan?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wia, scanning

I have code that scan file and save it on my path:

```
public ImageFile Scan()
    {
        var device = this._deviceInfo.Connect();

        var item = device.Items[1];
        var imageFile = (ImageFile)item.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG);

        return imageFile;
    }

  protected void btnscan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Object scanner in scanners)
        {
            if (ddlSelectDevice.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals(scanner.ToString()))
            {
                //var d = ddlSelectDevice.SelectedIndex as Scanner;
                var device = scanner as Scanner;
                if (device == null)
                {

                    return;
                }

                var image = device.Scan();

                var path = "~/Scanner/scan.jpeg";
                if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)))
                {
                    File.Delete(Server.MapPath(path));
                }
                image.SaveFile(Server.MapPath(path));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I save this image in database by convert to byte:

```
 private byte[] image2Byte()
    {
        string filePath = null;
        Byte[] bytes = null;

        if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Scanner/scan.jpeg")))
        {
            filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Scanner/scan.jpeg");
            return bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }
        else
        {
            filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Scanner/None.jpg");
            return bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }

    }
```

But my images usually have large size (up 400kB) and makes problem on load. How I can reduce image size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) to reduce the quality of the JPEG file. A quality of 80% is accaptable for most use cases.

```
using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData:true))
{
    imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                .Quality(80)
                .Save(outStream);
}
```

Comment: this package don't install in .netframework win project